# navigator related plugins not working in cordova latest version

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I upgraded my old cordova project to latest cordova version.

navigator related plugins not working in latest version

Details:

1. navigator.connection.type always returning unknown if network available also.
2. navigator.notification.alert not working
   navigator.notification.confirm not working

Please let me know anybody got the solution for above issues